# Concyclic Eccentric angles of an ellipse.

Tags: conic-sections

If $\;\alpha, \; \beta,\; \gamma,\; \delta\;$   are eccentric anlges of four conclyclic points on the standard ellipse $\; \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ . Then $\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta =\; ?$

Comment: See https://goo.gl/mmxCrL

Comment: You have a better and easier method

Comment: Well solved [*here*](https://goiit.com/t/doubt-from-ellipse/36200).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The points with eccentric angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ & $\delta$ are $(a\cos\alpha, b\sin \alpha)$, $(a\cos\beta, b\sin \beta)$, $(a\cos\gamma, b\sin \gamma)$ & $(a\cos\delta, b\sin \delta)$

I hope you can solve further by applying the condition of con-cyclic points which are the points of intersection of ellipse & its auxiliary circle.

Comment: Auxiliary Circle? Can you explain?

Comment: Alright, auxiliary circle is the circumcircle with center coincident with that of the ellipse & having a radius equal to the semi major axis of the ellipse.

Comment: I know that the auxiliary circle is the locus of foot of perpendiculars from the focus to any tangent of the ellipse. I asked whether the condition will prove the question or whether it'll give the answer...